# positive (semi)definite, negative (semi)definite and indefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite

When looking at a quadratic form in a matrix, I am not completely sure how to tell if is one of the answers from above.

-positive (semi)definite

-negative (semi)definite

-indefinite

how do i figure this out

Comment: This lecture from MIT might help you [Lecture 5: Positive Definite and Semidefinite Matrices](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-065-matrix-methods-in-data-analysis-signal-processing-and-machine-learning-spring-2018/video-lectures/lecture-5-positive-definite-and-semidefinite-matrices/)

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches.  One is to write the (symmetric) matrix associated the quadratic form, the other is to "complete the square", as the a deleted answer notes.

For example:
$$
q(x_1,x_2) = x_1^2 - 4x_1x_2 + x_2^2 = 
x_1^2 - 2x_1x_2 - 2x_2x_1 + x_2^2
$$
The matrix associated with this quadratic form is
$$
M = \pmatrix{1&-2\\-2&1}
$$
and we wish to determine its definiteness.  Applying [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_criterion) to both $M$ and $-M$ allows us to check if $M$ is positive/negative definite.  Since the $2 \times 2$ determinant $\det(M)$ is negative, we can conclude that $M$ is neither positive nor negative definite.

Now, $\det(M) \neq 0$, so $M$ is invertible.  Since $M$ is invertible without being positive/negative definite, it is invertible.

If $M$ were singular, we'd have to try something else.  In practice (with pencil and paper), one would find the eigenvalues of $M$.  If all non-zero eigenvalues have the same sign, then the singular $M$ is postive/negative semidefinite. Otherwise, $M$ would be indefinite.

---

Another approach to apply (especially for large matrices) is to attempt a Cholesky factorization.  If $M$ has a Cholesky factorization, it is positive semidefinite.  If $-M$ has a Cholesky factorization, it is negative semidefinite.  Otherwise, $M$ is neither.

In this case, we find $M$ and $-M$ have no Cholesky factorization

---

Equivalent (in a sense) to Cholesky factorization is the approach of completing the square.  We find
$$
q(x_1,x_2) = x_1^2 - 4x_1x_2 + x_2^2 = 
(x_1^2 - 4x_1x_2 + 4x_2^2) - 3x_2^2 = \\
(x_1 - 2x_2)^2 - 3x_2^2
$$
Correspondingly, we see that
$$
M = \pmatrix{1&0\\-2&1}^T\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-3}\pmatrix{1&0\\-2&1}
$$